# Is Russia funding environmentalist groups to protest fracking?

Tags: environment, russia, fracking

Leaked transcripts from a private Clinton speech suggest that Russia has given large amounts of money to environmentalist groups in Europe and the US to promote protests against fracking, according to [this article from October 2016](http://www.dailywire.com/news/9902/leaked-hillary-speech-suggests-russians-are-aaron-bandler).

Similar claims [were made publicly by NATO chief Anders Fogh Rasmussen in 2014](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/jun/19/russia-secretly-working-with-environmentalists-to-oppose-fracking) and in the (heavily pro-industry) documentary FrackNation in 2013.

Russia's otherwise negative stance on environmentalism (I'm thinking of the Arctic 30, for example) makes this claim hard to believe. Is there publicly available information that supports it?

Comment: According to your second source, Russia's motives would not be environmental, but *"to maintain European dependence on imported Russian gas"* by creating fake environmental groups in countries that depend on Russia's oil.

Comment: Given the devastating effect that fracking is having on the Russian economy, it would be irresponsible of the Russian government to fail to give money to groups opposing it.  Of course, unwise policy is no rarity in any government, but this particular behavior (funding nonprofits that  advance Russian interests) has been SOP for Putin since his KGB days.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara After registering I lost the account I used to make this question so I couldn't respond. Anyway part of the suspicion is that "fake environmental groups" are unlikely to have much influence so this is more likely to benefit the US, since anti-fracking protestors can now be dismissed as Commies. Also most environmentalist interests don't align with Russia (certainly an "environmentalist" group that embraces traditionally sourced oil rather than wind or solar would be suspicious). The other issue is that the claims are very vague while 100mil USD of support should leave a trace.